# Vimscript regex for tag

Tags: regex, vim

I currently have the following vimscript function to get the current HTML tag by the cursor:

```
fun s:GetCurrentTag()
return matchstr(matchstr(getline('.'),
\ '<\zs\(\w\|=\| \|''\|"\)*>\%'.col('.').'c'), '^\a*')
endf
```

This code was written by someone else so I'm not exactly sure what its doing.  Can someone provide a brief explanation.  I haven't been able to find any good vimscript regex documentation online.

However, what's most important is I want to change this function so that it can detect tags with `%` and `.` in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim's regular expressions are documented under `:help pattern`.  See also `:help design-documented`.

From the inside out,

1. `getline('.')` gets the current line as a String.
2. `matchstr(string, pat)` gets the portion of string that matches the pattern pat.
3. `<` matches a literal left angle bracket.
4. `\zs` means "start matching here", so that `<` will not be included.
5. `\(...\)` creates a group.
6. `\|` represents an alternative.  So the group matches either `\w` (a word character), `=` (literal),  (space), `'` (literal, doubled because it is inside a 'literal string'), or `"` (literal).
7. `*` means "zero or more, as many as possible" (greedy).  It applies to the previous item; in this case, it applies to the group.
8. `>` matxhes a literal right angle bracket.
9. `'\%' . col('.') . 'c'` matches at the current column.  So I think this only matches if the cursor is one character past the closing `>`.
10. Having matched the current tag (starting after the opening `<` and going one character past the closing `>`) another `matchstr()` selects the alphabetic part at the start.

This is not the way I would have written it.

This is a little simpler:

```
matchstr(getline('.'), '<\zs\a*\ze\(\w\|[= ''"]\)*>\%' . col('.') . 'c')
```

Probably just add `%\|\.\|` to the original version, or `%.` inside the square brackets in mine, and you will get what you want.